# Manual threads vs Parallel.Foreach in task scheduler

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a Windows Service that processes tasks created by users. This Service runs on a server with 4 cores. The tasks mostly involve heavy database work (generating a report for example). The server also has a few other services running so I don't want to spin up too many threads (let's say a maximum of 4).

If I use a `BlockingCollection<MyCustomTask>`, is it a better idea to create 4 Thread objects and use these to consume from the `BlockingCollection<MyCustomTask>` or should I use `Parallel.Foreach` to accomplish this?

I'm looking at the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) which contains a StaTaskScheduler which uses the former, like so (slightly modified the code for clarity):

```
var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfThreads).Select(i =>
                       {
                           var thread = new Thread(() =>
                           {
                               // Continually get the next task and try to execute it.
                               // This will continue until the scheduler is disposed and no more tasks remain.
                               foreach (var t in _tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                               {
                                   TryExecuteTask(t);
                               }
                           });
                           thread.IsBackground = true;
                           thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                           return thread;
                       }).ToList();

            // Start all of the threads
            threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
```

However, there's also a `BlockingCollectionPartitioner` in the same [ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) which would enable the use of `Parallel.Foreach` on a `BlockingCollection<Task>`, like so:

```
 var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<MyCustomTask>();
        Parallel.ForEach(blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), task =>
        {
            task.DoSomething();
        });
```

It's my understanding that the latter leverages the `ThreadPool`. Would using Parallel.ForEach have any benefits in this case?

Comment: What you have written doesn't make much sense. Tasks and Parallel.ForEach are based on Threads. So, you run threads to run tasks (e.g. run more threads). This solution will not help you with performance.

Comment: The Task is a custom made class (i.e. not System.Threading.Tasks.Task). I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: the TPL will opt to perform them in sequence and not in parallel if it determines that a set of tasks would gain little or no benefit
by running in parallel.And yes it leverages the ThreadPool and manage concurrency on your behalf

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it's possible for `Parallel.ForEach` to spin up too many thread pool threads if the blocking collection spends a lot of time being empty (this is discussed in Patterns of Parallel Programming, page 88). You said you only want 4 threads working on your "tasks", so be sure to limit the degree of parallelism via `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is relevant if Task class in your code has nothing to do with System.Threading.Tasks.Task.

As a simple rule, use Parallel.ForEach to run tasks that will end eventually. Like execute some work in parallel with some other work

Use Threads when they run routine for the whole life of application.

So, it looks like in your case you should use Threads approach.